# Prevent Wifi and mobile broadband from being turned off when phone is locked

Tags: security

On my old android 10 phone (an LG) if I pull down the shade when the phone is locked and try to turn off wifi or mobile broadband, it asks me for my password.  My new phone doesn't do that.  Is that a setting somewhere? or do the manufacturers change that for you?

--

Actually my old phone also doesn't let me power it off without the code.

Comment: Preventing data connectivity change from lock screen might be a security feature implemented by your LG vendor (Xiaomi does that too).